# Ajax Realtime user status change without page refresh

Tags: php, ajax

I have a div that goes green/red when the user logs in/out

with this php code:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_id='".$user_id."' LIMIT 1");
if(mysql_num_rows($results ) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){                      
      if($row['status'] === "1"){                       
        $status = 'online';                     
      }else{
         $status = 'offline';                   
      }
   }
}

<div class="'. $status .'">username</div>
```

how can I make it change the $status without the need to refresh the page to see the changes?
so if i have 100 guests on the site and one user logs in, all 100 guest will see green next to the user that logged in right away

any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Ajax would be able to do what your looking for, I recommend you review the following link:  http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp

Comment: I don't really understand how to do that, could you show me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

How you are showing list of guests? give `id attribute` to `username divs`. And then use `long polling` or `ajax at regular interval`( say every 1 seconds) to see who is/are online. and in `ajax success function` you can edit color to `div` by getting them by `Id` by jquery or native javascript.

Sample code for ajax using jquery, at every 1 second

```
function test()
{
$.ajax({
url:url,
data:{postingData:dt},
success:function(response) {
},
error: function (response) {
}
})
}
setInterval('test()',1000);
```

In phpyou need to search your user table to select online users and can send json array of all loggedin users.
You would then in jquery success function, need to process this json array and change color of loggedin users.

Comment: could you show me how to do the check every 1 second?

Comment: @Gadgetster, I updated to add a sample code for ajax call every 1 seconds.

Comment: how do I tell it to check activity and how do I run a php query with that?